# Management of pdf with django through a template and sent as an attachment of an electronic mail

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, xhtml2pdf

I am creating a site for student registrations with the django framework.

I have arrived at a place where I have to display the form to the user and I receive the information entered after treatment I have to send an email to the user user containing the information he has entered by putting them in a PDF which I must generate from a template containing the context dictionary.

For the moment the PDF that I can generate is possible only by sending it to the browser through the function `HttpResponse`, but the problem with that is that it is the user who decides to download it or not and I have more possibility to put the hand on the pdf to send it as an attachment.

I thought to open a database where there will be a field of type `models.FileField`, generate the pdf with the context dictionary through the library `xhtml2pdf` that I could save in the database with a signal and then send the email by taking the file as attachment.

None of the methods I tried to achieve this are successful for the moment. Here is my code:

## utils.py

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template

from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):

    template = get_template(template_src)
    html = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type="application/pdf")
    return None
```

## models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save

from django.core.mail import EmailMessage, EmailMultiAlternatives

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class MyModel(models.Model):
    order_id    = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    nom         = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email       = models.EmailField()
    pdf         = models.FileField(upload_to="pdfs", null=True, blank=True)

def create_order_id(instance, new_order_id=None):

    order_id = instance.id

    if new_order_id is not None:
        order_id = new_order_id


    qs = MyModel.objects.filter(order_id=order_id)
    exists = qs.exists()

    if exists:
        new_order_id = "%s-%s" %(order_id.first().id)
        return create_order_id(instance, new_order_id)


    return order_id


def pre_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.order_id :
        instance.new_order_id = create_order_id(instance)




def send_mail_insciption(instance):

    subject = "Thank you"
    from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    to_email = [instance.email]
    body = "Votre inscription"

    email_pdf = EmailMultiAlternatives(

        subject = subject,
        body =body,
        from_email = from_email,
        to=to_email,    
        )


    email_pdf.attach_alternative(instance.pdf, "application/pdf")
    email_pdf.send()


def post_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    send_mail_insciption(instance)




pre_save.connect(pre_save_receiver, sender=MyModel )
post_save.connect(post_save_receiver, sender=MyModel)


#views.py

def pdf_genarete(request):

    form = MyModelForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():

        nom = form.cleaned_data.get("nom")
        email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
        obj = MyModel.objects.create(nom=nom, email=email)

        context = {"models_instance": obj}

        pdf = render_to_pdf("pdfapp/template_pdf.html", context)
        filename = "mypdf_{}.pdf".format(obj.order_id)
        pdf.save()
        obj.pdf.save(filename, File(BytesIO(pdf.content)))

        return redirect(reverse("home"))

    return render(request, "pdfapp/formulaire.html", {"form": form})
```

After execution here is the error on the terminal:

```
 File "/home/michel/saintexupery/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 769, in save_base
    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,
  File "/home/michel/saintexupery/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 178, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/home/michel/saintexupery/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 178, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/home/michel/saintexupery/saintexupry/pdfapp/models.py", line 69, in post_save_receiver
    send_mail_insciption(instance)
  File "/home/michel/saintexupery/saintexupry/pdfapp/models.py", line 65, in send_mail_insciption
    email_pdf.send()
  File "/home/michel/saintexupery/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 294, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/home/michel/saintexupery/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 110, in send_messages
    sent = self._send(message)
  File "/home/michel/saintexupery/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 124, in _send
    message = email_message.message()
  File "/home/michel/saintexupery/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 254, in message
    msg = self._create_message(msg)
  File "/home/michel/saintexupery/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 440, in _create_message
    return self._create_attachments(self._create_alternatives(msg))
  File "/home/michel/saintexupery/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 450, in _create_alternatives
    msg.attach(self._create_mime_attachment(*alternative))
  File "/home/michel/saintexupery/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 393, in _create_mime_attachment
    Encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/encoders.py", line 32, in encode_base64
    encdata = str(_bencode(orig), 'ascii')
  File "/home/michel/saintexupery/env/lib/python3.6/base64.py", line 534, in encodebytes
    _input_type_check(s)
  File "/home/michel/saintexupery/env/lib/python3.6/base64.py", line 520, in _input_type_check
    raise TypeError(msg) from err
TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not FieldFile
```

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace of your error to your question, so that we can try to identify where the error is originating

Comment: Did you generate your pdf file properly?  I can show you a way to send it to emails without saving any file to the database, is that what you want? before that, just delete this [French Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49992170/g%c3%a9n%c3%a9ration-de-pdf-avec-django-et-lenvoie-de-ce-pdf-en-pi%c3%a8ce-jointe) (even though I speak French, but we are in English StackOverflow,other languages are not allowed), let's consider this as the real question

Comment: @Mic try changing `obj.pdf.save(filename, File(BytesIO(pdf.content)))` to `obj.pdf.save(filename, BytesIO(pdf.content))`

Comment: When I apply this method, they are the same errors :
The above exception (memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'FieldFile') was the direct cause of the following exception

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta I just want to be able to send the pdf through the template containing the context dictionary, if there is an opportunity to do it otherwise I am open to any suggestions

Comment: share you complete error traceback in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I your code you have this part:

```
def send_mail_insciption(instance):
    ...
    email_pdf.attach_alternative(instance.pdf, "application/pdf")
    email_pdf.send()
```

The error message (and traceback) say that the email expects bytes as attachment, but `instance.pdf` is a [`FieldFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile).

Try converting the file to bytes, maybe using `instance.pdf.read()` and let us know if that solves the problem.

Comment: When I apply this method here is the error that it gives: ValueError at /pdfapp/pdf_genarete
The 'pdf' attribute has no file associated with it.

Comment: Hm, this error usually means that the file does not exist. What result do you get if you add `print(instance.pdf.name, instance.pdf.size)` before you send the email? Does it show the correct file?

Comment: Hello ! Thank you very much the method you showed me by reading the file by the 'read' method worked. Just something bizzard comes to know that I send the attachment, it is visible when I consult my mailbox on my phone (on mobile) but by consulting my email with the PC I can not see attachment . How is it possible ? Did you ever meet that?

Comment: @Mic no, I have not encountered the problem with not seeing the attachment in your PC.